# Create shipment and invoice in mass action

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, invoice, shipment

I want to create shipment + Invoice using mass action in order grid.

Can anyone tell me the approach to do this?
Share code if possible otherwise approach would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search for any tutorial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently worked on this feature both (Invoice and Shipment). First you have to add `Uicomponent` in your module

Path: `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
            <massaction name="listing_massaction">
<action name="order_invoice">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_mass</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Invoice</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ordermass/order/massInvoice"/>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Invoice</item>
                                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to create invoice for selected items?</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>   
                <action name="order_ship">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_ship_mass</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship (Email)</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ordermass/order/massShip"/>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship (Email)</item>
                                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to create shipment for selected items?</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
</massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

After that Add routes in your module
Path: `app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="ordermass" frontName="ordermass">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> For Invoice Controller

Path: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassInvoice.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

class MassInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{

    protected $orderManagement;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService
     */
    protected $_invoiceService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction
     */
    protected $_transaction;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
        $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->_transaction = $transaction;
    }

    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $countInvoiceOrder = 0; $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers = '';
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');

        $username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
        $appendusername = "(".$username.")";

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $order) {
            if (!$order->getEntityId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $loadedOrder = $model->load($order->getEntityId());

            if($loadedOrder->canInvoice()) {

            // Create invoice for this order
            $invoice = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService')->prepareInvoice($loadedOrder);
            //$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            $invoice->setShippingAmount($loadedOrder->getShippingAmount());
            $invoice->setBaseShippingAmount($loadedOrder->getBaseShippingAmount());
            $invoice->setTaxAmount($loadedOrder->getTaxAmount());
            $invoice->setBaseTaxAmount($loadedOrder->getBaseTaxAmount());
            $invoice->setSubtotal($loadedOrder->getSubtotal());
            $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($loadedOrder->getBaseSubtotal());
            $invoice->setGrandTotal($loadedOrder->getGrandTotal());
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($loadedOrder->getBaseGrandTotal());

            // Register as invoice item
            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
            $invoice->register();
            // Save the invoice to the order
            $transaction = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction')
            ->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
            $transaction->save();

            //send notification code
            $loadedOrder->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Notified customer about invoice #%1. '.$appendusername, $invoice->getId())
            )->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->save();

            if ($loadedOrder->canShip()) {
            $loadedOrder->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
            $loadedOrder->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $loadedOrder->addStatusToHistory($loadedOrder->getStatus(), 'Order status set to processing using Mass Invoice action '.$appendusername);
            $loadedOrder->save();
            }

            $countInvoiceOrder++;
            }
            else {
                if (empty($NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers)){
                $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers = $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers.$loadedOrder->getIncrementId();
                }
                else{
                $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers = $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers.", ".$loadedOrder->getIncrementId();    
                }
            }
        }
        $countNonInvoiceOrder = $collection->count() - $countInvoiceOrder;

        if ($countNonInvoiceOrder && $countInvoiceOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 order(s) Invoice created successfully.', $countInvoiceOrder));
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invoice already created for %1 order(s).', $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers));
        } elseif ($countNonInvoiceOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invoice already created for %1 order(s).', $NonInvoiceOrdernuumbers));
        }

        if ($countInvoiceOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 order(s) Invoice created successfully.', $countInvoiceOrder));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

> For Shipment Controller

Path: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassShip.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

class MassShip extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{

    protected $orderManagement;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }

    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $countShipOrder = 0; $NonShipOrdernuumbers = '';
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');

        $username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
        $appendusername = "(".$username.")";

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $order) {
            if (!$order->getEntityId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $loadedOrder = $model->load($order->getEntityId());

            if($loadedOrder->canShip()) {


            $convertOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
            $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($loadedOrder);

            // Loop through order items
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
                // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
                if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
                // Create shipment item with qty
                $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
                // Add shipment item to shipment
                $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }

            // Register shipment
            $shipment->register();
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            try {
                // Save created shipment and order
                $shipment->save();
                $shipment->getOrder()->save();
                //send notification code
                $loadedOrder->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Notified customer about shipment #%1. '.$appendusername, $shipment->getId())
                )->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->save();

                $itemsCheck = $loadedOrder->getItemsCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
                foreach ($itemsCheck as $item) {
                    if (! $item->getQtyToShip() || $item->getIsVirtual()) { 
                    continue;
                    }
                    $item->setQtyShipped($item->getQtyToShip());
                    $item->save();
                    $Norder = $shipment->getOrder()->load( $shipment->getOrder()->getId() );
                    $Norder->save();
                }

                // Send email
                $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
                    ->notify($shipment);

                $shipment->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
            }

            if ($loadedOrder->canInvoice()) {
            $loadedOrder->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
            $loadedOrder->setStatus('shipped');
            $loadedOrder->addStatusToHistory('shipped', 'Order status set to shipped using Mass Ship action. '.$appendusername);
            $loadedOrder->save();
            }

            $countShipOrder++;
            }
            else {
                if (empty($NonShipOrdernuumbers)){
                $NonShipOrdernuumbers = $NonShipOrdernuumbers.$loadedOrder->getIncrementId();
                }
                else{
                $NonShipOrdernuumbers = $NonShipOrdernuumbers.", ".$loadedOrder->getIncrementId();  
                }
            }
        }
        $countNonShipOrder = $collection->count() - $countShipOrder;

        if ($countNonShipOrder && $countShipOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 order(s) Shipment created successfully.', $countShipOrder));
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Shipment already created for %1 order(s).', $NonShipOrdernuumbers));
        } elseif ($countNonShipOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Shipment already created for %1 order(s).', $NonShipOrdernuumbers));
        }

        if ($countShipOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 order(s) Shipment created successfully.', $countShipOrder));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

**This is tested code, I hope this will help**

Comment: $collection->getItems() not working for me when i am trying to do mass action

Comment: I tested the code in 2.3.5-p1 but its not working. The mass action should appear in the actions dropdown in the "Orders" page, right?!